# How to determine version of the script, and update

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make selfupdating script but I am not sure how to do that.
At the moment I am runing init script which copying final from samba directory script into work directory.

My script gonna work on 150 computers in few stores of our company. 
I am thinking about checking version from my final script and version from web, and download final.ps1 if newer is avalible.

Versioning format is date yyyymmdd (ex 20150611), simple to compare and debug.

Firstly I am trying to get version from my final script

```
Function checkVersion {
    Param ([switch]$version)
    if($version) {
      Write-Output "20150611"
  }
}
myscript.ps1 -version
```

But that doesn't working. Maybe someone tried write similar function?

Comment: They say use robocopy. I'd say write a simple getter script that'll run on a timely basis that will copy your complex script from a central location, then run that one. Also I wouldn't trust web servers to distribute Powershell scripts, as they might be hacked and your servers will just eat the virus instead of an actual script, and use the VPN/internal secured network and a known signature to sign and distribute the script.

Comment: In your code sample I see you calling the script with the `-version` switch but i don't see where you try and call the function in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to run the script with a parameter `-Version` to output the script's version number. You also want an (auto-)update function that calls determines the version number of a "most recent" script and updates the current script in case the remote version is more recent.

A feature to return the version number could be implemented like this:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [switch]$Version
)

$MyVersion = '20150611'

if ($Version.IsPresent) {
  $MyVersion
  exit 0
}
```

Updating and re-running the current file can be done with something like this:

```psh
$scriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$mostRecent = '\\server\share\final.ps1'

function Test-Update($file) {
  return ($MyVersion -lt (& $file -Version))
}

if (Test-Update $mostRecent) {
  (Copy-Item $mostRecent $scriptPath -Force)  # Run Copy-Item in an expression, so
                                              # it's completed before re-running
                                              # the script!
  & $scriptPath
  exit 0
}
```

However, with that said, if you have a most recent version of the script script on a file share, why aren't you running that most recent script version from the file share in the first place?

Comment: thank you very much, it's almost exactly what I wanted to do. I can't run script from network location because not every time users will be in our network, but it must do job :)